# Error calling a predefined query on sqlite (React-Native)

Tags: sqlite, react-native

I need call a predefined query, i have one menu with 4 items on the home of the app and i need call some categories, i have this on the menu:

```
<TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => fetchCategorySingle('Cars')}
          style={styles.buttonBox}>
          <Text style={styles.TextColor}>Cars</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
```

Then on my db helper file i do:

```
export const fetchCategorySingle = () => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.transaction(tx => {
      tx.executeSql(
        'SELECT tema FROM temas WHERE tema LIKE "car"',
        [],
        (_, results) => {
          var len = results.rows.length;
          for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            let row = results.rows.item(i);
            console.log(`Model: ${row.tema}, Categoria: ${row.descripcion}`);
          }
        },
        (_, err) => {
          reject(err);
        },
      );
    });
  });
  return promise;
};
```

but i get this error:

> TypeError: (0,_DB.default) is not a
>   function.(in'(0,Db.defalt)('cars')',(0,Db.defalt) is undefined

Y try to send the word as a variable too, on the fetchCategorySingle = () parameter but i can't find the right way

example of what i try:

```
export const fetchCategorySingle = search => {
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var query = "SELECT tema FROM temas WHERE tema LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
```

Comment: It looks like the problem has nothing to do with the database at this point, rather on how to properly define functions and callbacks, etc.  Exactly what line is the error occurring?

Comment: i dont get a line, just the error what i define on yellow, then on "createReactClass" $ argument from the file TouchableOpacity.js 264:45

Comment: Then you need to learn and use technique to narrow down the problem.  You are already using `console.log`.  Place more `console.log` calls at key locations to determine what lines are executing and which lines are "skipped" when an error occurs.  BTW, doesn't `264:45` indicate the line and column of the error?

Comment: yes, youre right, i can make the query now if i define the function on app.js but not when i click the button on the menu, there i got the same error again, i try searching on youtube "how to make a predefined query on react native", i dont see how to display the results when i click on the item of the menu (in the homescreen). Do I make myself clear? Or should I rephrase the question.